# Lowest-Base Palindrome

Tags: code-golf, palindrome, base-conversion

Given a number \$n\$, write a program that finds the smallest base \$b ≥ 2\$ such that \$n\$ is a palindrome in base \$b\$. For example, an input of \$28\$ should return the base \$3\$ since \$28_{10} = 1001_3\$. Although \$93\$ is a palindrome in both base \$2\$ and base \$5\$, the output should be \$2\$ since \$2<5\$.

### Input

A positive integer \$n < 2^{31}\$.

### Output

Return the smallest base \$b ≥ 2\$ such that the base \$b\$ representation of \$n\$ is a palindrome. Do not assume any leading zeros.

Samples (input => output):

> \$11 \to 10\$
>
> \$32 \to 7\$
>
> \$59 \to 4\$
>
> \$111 \to 6\$

### Rules

The shortest code wins.

Comment: I think base should be limited.

Comment: No, I mean the base to check. For example, I can check up to base 10, or I can check up to base 36, which uses 0-9a-z. And I can even check up to base 127 which uses ASCII characters. You should limit base to check up.

Comment: @Snack: What's the problem with higher bases? Independently of the choice of symbols, a base 1000 number will either be a palindrome or not.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Sorry.

Comment: Are you asking for a function, or a full program?, And does it have to take command-line input or can I hardcode it?, Is the output printed or returned?

Comment: @Ourous: A function. Hardcoding is fine. Output is returned.

Comment: Interesting anecdote: n in base n-1 is always 11 for n >= 2 and thus a palindrome is always possible.

Comment: @Cruncher: `n` can be 1 and 2 is not a base 1 palindrome. However, every positive `n` is a base `n + 1` palindrome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if an integer is a palindrome in a given radix (base)](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22449/determine-if-an-integer-is-a-palindrome-in-a-given-radix-base)

Comment: @Dennis How is 2 not a base 1 palindrome? It's 11. Or II, or 2 of whatever symbol you use. Actually all base 1 numbers are palindromes. And I said n >= 2, because I don't know what on earth base 0 would be.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma definitely related. Shaky whether it's a dupe or not

Comment: @Cruncher: I didn't consider 1 a valid base. OK, there's apparently a unary number system, but the question rules base 1 out.

Comment: @Dennis Everyone knows unary! You've been doing it with your fingers since you learned to count! Anyway, my comment was more of an aside. I was going to say n >= 3, but since it was mathematically true for n=2, I decided to strengthen it a bit.

Comment: @Cruncher: Exactly! That's why I did not provide an upper bound for the base.

Comment: This is OEIS [A016026](http://oeis.org/A016026).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Home/), 19 bytes / GolfScript, 23 bytes

```
q~:N;1{)_N\b_W%=!}g
```

or

```
~:N;1{).N\base.-1%=!}do
```

Try it online:

- [CJam](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)
- [GolfScript](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IjkzIiAjIFNpbXVsYXRlIGlucHV0IGZyb20gU1RESU4uCgp%2BOk47MXspLk5cYmFzZS4tMSU9IX1kbw%3D%3D)

#### Examples

```
$ cjam base.cjam <<< 11; echo
10
$ cjam base.cjam <<< 111; echo
6
$ golfscript base.gs <<< 11
10
$ golfscript base.gs <<< 111
6
```

#### How it works

```
q~:N;   # Read the entire input, interpret it and save the result in “N”.
1       # Push 1 (“b”).
{       #
  )     # Increment “b”.
  _N\   # Duplicate “b”, push “N” and swap.
  b     # Push the array of digits of “N” in base “b”.
  _W%   # Duplicate the array and reverse it.
  =!    # Compare the arrays.
}g      # If they're not equal, repeat the loop.
```

For GolfScript, `q~` is `~`, `_` is `.`, `b` is `base`, `W` is `-1` and `g` is `do`.

Answer (score 5):

#### GolfScript, 20 characters

```
~:x,2>{x\base.-1%=}?
```

A different approach with GolfScript other than [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)'. It avoids the costly explicit loop in favour of a *find* operator. [Try online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyIzMiIKCn46eCwyPnt4XGJhc2UuLTElPX0%2FCg%3D%3D&run=true).

```
~:x        # interpret and save input to variable x
,2>        # make a candidate list 2 ... x-1 (note x-1 is the maximum possible base)
{          # {}? find the item on which the code block yields true
  x\       # push x under the item under investigation
  base     # perform a base conversion
  .-1%     # make a copy and reverse it
  =        # compare reversed copy and original array
}?
```

Comment: Clever! However, this does not work if `x = 1` or `x = 2`. Both are single-digit, base `x + 1` palindromes, so `x))` should fix it.

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, <s>67</s> 66 bytes

```
g[n_]:=For[i=1,1>0,If[(d=n~IntegerDigits~++i)==Reverse@d,Break@i]]
```

Can't really compete with GolfScript here in terms of code size, but the result for 2<sup>32</sup> is basically returned instantly.

Comment: Nice. The function doesn't have to be named though, does it? Could you just use an unnamed function?

Comment: (Also, is it possible to use `PalindromeQ` for the reverse check?)

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>12</s> 9 bytes

Unless I've missed a trick (it's late!), this should work for all numbers up to and including at least `2**53-1`.

In my (admittedly limited and entirely random) testing, I've gotten results up to base <s>`11601`</s> `310,515`(!) so far. Not too shabby when you consider JavaScript only natively supports bases `2` to `36`.

```
@ìX êê}a2
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=QOxYIOrqfWEy&input=MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDk=)

- Thanks to [ETH](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions) for pointing out something new to me that saved 3 bytes and increased the efficiency considerably.

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of integer `U`.

```
@     }a2
```

Starting with `2`, return the first number that returns true when passed through the following function, with `X` being the current number

```
ìX
```

Convert `U` to an array of base `X` digits.

```
êê
```

Test if that array is a palindrome.

Comment: 1) Yes. Blame the beer for that balls up! :D 2) Nice; never knew `N.ì(n)` could handle bases greater than `36`. Thanks for that.

Comment: Yeah, the base-36 alphabet doesn't matter for `N.ì(n)` since we're using raw integers ;-)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, 88 bytes

```
f=function(n){for(a=b='+1';a^a.split('').reverse().join('');a=n.toString(++b));return+b}
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
f = function(n) {
    for(a = b = '+1'; // This is not palindrome, but equals 1 so we have at least one iteration
        a ^ a.split('').reverse().join(''); // test a is palindrome
        a = n.toString(++b));
    return+b
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## J - 28 char

```
#.inv~(-.@-:|.@)(1+]^:)^:_&2
```

Explained:

- `#.inv~` - Expand left argument to the base in the right argument.
- `(-.@-:|.@)` - Return 0 if the expansion is palindromic, and 1 otherwise.
- `(1+]^:)` - Increment the right argument by one if we returned 1, else take no action.
- `^:_` - Repeat the above incrementing until it takes no action.
- `&2` - Prepare the right argument as 2, making this a function of one argument.

Examples:

```
   #.inv~(-.@-:|.@)(1+]^:)^:_&2 (28)
3
   #.inv~(-.@-:|.@)(1+]^:)^:_&2 every 93 11 32 59 111  NB. perform on every item
2 10 7 4 6
   #.inv~(-.@-:|.@)(1+]^:)^:_&2 every 1234 2345 3456 4567 5678 6789
22 16 11 21 31 92
```

Comment: `2+1 i.~[#.inv"*(-:|.@)~2+i.` for 27 bytes. (Don't want to post it separately. I will just leave it here.)

Comment: @randomra I would count that as 29 because trains need parens to be used inline; mine saves a character by having a conjunction at the top level.

Comment: I think the majority's stand on scoring is the paren-less counting with any unnamed function though there is always an argument about this. Anyway, I will leave it here and everybody can choose how he/she scores it. :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 79 bytes

```python
def f(n,b=2):
 l=[];m=n
 while m:l+=m%b,;m/=b
 return(l==l[::-1])*b or f(n,b+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxBCoMwEEDR/ZxiNoVMtZRJ6aKROYm4CY0YSEYJEenpU8H9/2/71WVV29o3zDgb7b1YcoBJxmnIooDHElPA7FIn@eb7IT/FA5ZQ96ImiaTRuQdPdPe4lovomNq18UmpRN32aghwK1GrORuixgwvC@8PMPMf)

*-1 bytes thanks to 97.100.97.109*

I'm not sure what input/output format the question wanted. I wrote a function. The code uses an optional input `b` to track the current base it's testing. The `while` loops converts the number to a list of digits in base `b`.

The last line returns `b` if `l` is a palindrome, and recursively tries the next `b` otherwise. The index-by-Boolean trick doesn't work here because it would cause both options to be evaluated regardless of the Boolean, and the recursion would never bottom out.

Comment: So this will not work with arbitrarily high bases right? If the lowest base that a number has a palindrome is like 10000 then you'll get a stack overflow?

Comment: @Cruncher It depends of the implementation of Python. It will overflow when run with CPython, but not with [Stackless Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/StacklessPython), which does tail call optimization and so has no recursion limit (though I haven't actually tested it).

Comment: [82 bytes.](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMGCpaUlaboWN4NSUtMU0jTydJJsjTStuBRybKNjrXNt87gUyjMyc1IVcq1ytG2jc1WTgKL6-rZJXApFqSWlRXkKOYq2OdFWVrqGsYl5KRATtA0184sUkqAmK6cBOZkKmXkK0YaGOsZGOqaWOoaGhrFWBUWZeSUaaRqZmpoQpTDHAAA)

Comment: @97.100.97.109 Thanks, it turns out avoiding the `and` is even shorter

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 105 bytes

```
function f(n){for(var b=2,c,d;d=[];++b){for(c=n;c;c=c/b^0)d.push(c%b);if(d.join()==d.reverse())return b}}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/wR4Wf/1/

Note that this implementation also works correctly for large bases. For example, `f(10014)` returns 1668 (10014 is 66 in base 1668).

Comment: This is nice. You can even `s/var b=2,c,d/b=d=2/` to gain 6 more bytes ;)

Answer (score 1):

### R, <s>122</s> 95 bytes

```
function(n)(2:n)[sapply(2:n,function(x){r={};while(n){r=c(n%%x,r);n=n%/%x};all(r==rev(r))})][1]
```

**Three-year old solution at 122 bytes:**

```
f=function(n)(2:n)[sapply(sapply(2:n,function(x){r=NULL;while(n){r=c(n%%x,r);n=n%/%x};r}),function(x)all(x==rev(x)))][1]
```

With some explanations:

```
f=function(n)(2:n)[sapply(
                    sapply(2:n,function(x){ #Return the decomposition of n in bases 2 to n
                                 r=NULL
                                 while(n){
                                     r=c(n%%x,r)
                                     n=n%/%x}
                                     r
                                     }
                           ),
                    function(x)all(x==rev(x))) #Check if palindrome
                   ][1] #Return the first (i. e. smallest) for which it is
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + coreutils, 100 bytes

```
for((b=1;b++<=$1;)){
p=`dc<<<${b}o$1p`
c=tac
((b<17))&&c=rev
[ "$p" = "`$c<<<$p`" ]&&echo $b&&exit
}
```

Uses `dc` to do base formatting.  The tricky thing is `dc`'s format is different for n > 16.

Testcases:

```
$ ./lowestbasepalindrome.sh 11
10
$ ./lowestbasepalindrome.sh 32
7
$ ./lowestbasepalindrome.sh 59
4
$ ./lowestbasepalindrome.sh 111
6
$
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
ḟoS=↔`B⁰2
```

Thanks @Zgarb for -2!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9odXNr/8K24oKH/@G4n29TPeKGlGBC4oGwMv///1sxMSwzMiw1OSwxMTFd)

#### Explanation

```
ḟ(      )2  -- find least number ≥ 2 that satisfies:
     `B⁰    --   convert input to base (` flips arguments)
  S=↔       --   is palindrome (x == ↔x)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Note: Pyth is newer than this question, so this answer is not eligible to win.

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
fq_jQTjQT2
```

[Try it here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fq_jQTjQT2&input=111&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 83 bytes

```scala
def s(n:Int)=(for(b<-2 to n;x=Integer.toString(n,b);if(x==x.reverse))yield(b)).min
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
¼[¼¾вÂQ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0J7oQ3sO7buw6XBToPL//4ZGxiamZuYWlgYA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 84 + 1 (-p) = 85 bytes

```perl
$\=1;{++$\;my@r;$n=$_;do{push@r,$n%$\}while$n=int$n/$\;@t=@r;map$_-pop@t&&redo,@r}}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpRCoMwDADQy2T@qAw/BoNSyEEKIliwoEmIFRmlVzfr93sSdf@YQfCTK30PwR0/VAfkYXYrF7nODXUAekGo95b22ChRBnq3i9m3fCwC8ygsmLtO48oDaq3F7Puw5MR02ih/)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 72 bytes

```js
F=(n,b=2)=>eval(`for(t=n,a=c="";t;t=t/b|0)a=t%b+a,c+=t%b`)^a?F(n,b+1):b

console.log(F(11) == 10)

console.log(F(32) == 7)

console.log(F(59) == 4)

console.log(F(111) == 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica 42 bytes

A variation of Martin Ender's entry. Makes use of `IntegerReverse` (made available in version 10.3) which dispenses with `IntegerDigits`.

```
(i=2;While[#~IntegerReverse~i !=#,i++];i)&
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 103 bytes

```java
n->{int b=1,l;for(String s;!(s=n.toString(n,++b)).equals(new StringBuffer(s).reverse()+""););return b;}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hY8/T8MwEMX3foqj01lpLQXEgKwwsDHQpSNicNxL5eKeg/8EoSqfPbhNGVGlu@Hee9Lv3kEPeu174sPuczJOxwhv2vJpAWA5Uei0Idicz4sABl@LvKcALFRRx7JlYtLJGtgAQwMTr59P53Db1CunOh9wm4LlPUR1h7FhmfwsIK@qqhVC0lfWLiLTN8zOS@46ChiFDDRQiISiWi6FEipQyoGhVeOkZnifW1fg1x8Gb3dwLB2u0PcP0GIusP2JiY7S5yT7YiXHyNJgXYtLl38DD/c3Ao9PNwL1H2NcjNMv)

```java
n->{                          // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  int b=1,                    //  Base-integer, starting at 1
      l;                      //  Length temp integer
  for(String s;               //  Temp String
      !(s=n.toString(n,++b))  //   Set the String to `n` in base `b+1`
                              //   (by first increase `b` by 1 using `++b`)
       .equals(new StringBuffer(s).reverse()+"");
                              //   And continue looping as long as it's not a palindrome
  );                          //  End of loop
  return b;                   //  Return the resulting base integer
}                             // End of method
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
2b@ŒḂ¥1#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98oyeHopIc7mg4tNVT@f7j9UdMaoJiFjoKlsY6CoaGOgrGRjoKpJYhtCAA)

### How it works

```
2b@ŒḂ¥1# - Main link. Takes an integer n on the left
     ¥   - Group the previous 2 links into a dyad f(b, n):
 b@      -   Convert n to base b
   ŒḂ    -   Is palindrome?
2     1# - Count up b = 2, 3, 4, ... returning the first b that's true under f(b, n)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 43 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)

```ruby
->n{(2..).find{d=n.digits _1
d==d.reverse}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3tXXt8qo1jPT0NPXSMvNSqlNs8_RSMtMzS4oV4g25UmxtU_SKUstSi4pTa2uhWswLFNyiDQ1jFRSUFQwNuEA8YyMwT8EczDO1hPBMuCAqgUqBPDOI9gULIDQA)

Comment: `n.digits(_1)` => `n.digits _1`