# All your base palindromic belong to us

Tags: code-golf, sequence, base-conversion, palindrome

Generate the sequence *number of bases in which `n` is a palindrome* ([OEIS A126071](https://oeis.org/A126071)).

Specifically, the sequence is defined as follows: given a number `n`, express it in base `a` for `a = 1,2, ..., n`, and count how many of those expressions are palindromic. "Palindromic" is understood in terms of reversing the base-`a` digits of the expression as atomic units (thanks, [@Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner)). As an example, consider `n = 5`:

- `a=1`: the expression is `11111`: palindromic
- `a=2`: the expression is `101`: palindromic
- `a=3`: the expression is `12`: not palindromic
- `a=4`: the expression is `11`: palindromic
- `a=5`: the expression is `10`: not palindromic

Therefore the result for `n=5` is `3`. Note that OEIS uses bases `2, ..., n+1` instead of `1, ..., n` (thanks, [@beaker](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42892/beaker)). It's equivalent, because the expressions in base `1` and `n+1` are always palindromic.

The first values of the sequence are

```
 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 5, ...
```

Input is a positive integer `n`. Output is the first `n` terms of the sequence.

The program should theoretically work (given enough time and memory) for any `n` up to limitations caused by your default data type in any internal computations.

All functions allowed. Lowest number of bytes wins.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28404/lowest-base-palindrome)

Comment: If it's helpful to anyone, it's worth noting that a number n is also always palindromic in base n-1.

Comment: This is [A126071](https://oeis.org/A126071)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Pyth, 13 bytes

```
mlf_ITjLdSdSQ
```

The brevity of this is mostly due to the `I`nvaluable "`I`nvariant" command.

```
msf_ITjLdSdSQ       implicit: Q=input
m         d         map lambda d over
           SQ       Inclusive range 1 to Q
      jLdSd         Convert d to all the bases between 1 and d
  f                  filter lambda T:
   _IT                 is invariant under reverse
 l                  number that are invariant under reverse
```

If `True` is an acceptable output for `1`, `msm_IjdkSdSQ` (12 bytes) works.

Try it [here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=mlf_ITjLdSdSQ&input=10&debug=1).

Comment: See [FryAmTheEggman's suggestion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/141112/count-the-palindromes/141127?noredirect=1#comment346044_141127) to use `_I#` rather than `f_IT` (I'm not 100% sure it was available, but it [seems to have been](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/blob/c2ab5c69bfaed7fe792de4abe0fdf5dc8fdeb0ff/pyth.py#L187)).

Answer (score 7):

## Jelly, 12 bytes

```
bRµ=UP€S
RÇ€
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=YlLCtT1VUOKCrFPCtlLDh-KCrA&input=&args=MTA)

An old 14-byte version  (The Jelly interpreter had a bug that made converting to unary impossible)

```
bR‘$µ=UP€S
RÇ€
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=YlLigJgkwrU9VVDigqxTClLDh-KCrA&input=&args=MTA)

#### How it works

```
bR‘$µ=UP€S  Helper link. Argument: z

 R‘$        Apply range and increment, i.e., map z to [2, ..., z + 1].
            In the non-competing version R simply maps z to [1, ... z].
b           Convert z to each of the bases to the right.
    µ       Begin a new, monadic chain. Argument: base conversions
     =U     Compare the digits of each base with the reversed digits.
            = has depth 0, so [1,2,3]=[1,3,3] yields [1,0,1].
       P€   Take the product of the innermost arrays.
         S  Sum all resulting Booleans.


RÇ€         Main link. Argument: n

R           Yield [1, ..., n].
 Ç€         Apply the helper link to each.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 19 <s>20</s> bytes

```
:"0@XK:Q"K@:YAtP=A+
```

Uses [current release (10.1.0)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/10.1.0), which is earlier than this
challenge.

[**Try it online**!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OiIwQFhLOlEiS0A6WUF0UD1BKw&input=MTA)

#### Explanation

```
:            % vector [1,2,...,N], where "N" is implicit input
"            % for each number in that vector
  0          % push 0
  @          % push number 1,2,...N corresponding to current iteration, say "n" 
  XK         % copy n to clipboard
  :Q         % vector [2,3,...,n+1]
  "          % for each number "m" in that vector
    K        % push n
    @:       % vector [1,2,...,m]
    YA       % express n in base m with symbols 1,2,...,m
    tP       % duplicate and permute
    =A       % 1 if all entries are equal (palindrome), 0 otherwise
    +        % add that number
             % implicitly close the two loops and display stack contents
```

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, 20 bytes

```
ri{)_,f{)b_W%=}1bp}/
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri%7B)_%2Cf%7B)b_W%25%3D%7D1bp%7D%2F&input=20)

Answer (score 2):

### ES6, 149 bytes

```
n=>[...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>[...Array(i)].reduce((c,_,j)=>c+(''+(a=q(i+1,j+2,[]))==''+a.reverse()),1),q=(n,b,d)=>n<b?[n,...d]:q(n/b|0,b,[n%b,...d]))
```

Works for bases > 36 too.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 97 bytes

```python
c=1;n=int(input())
for b in range(2,n):
	a=[];z=n
	while z:a+=[z%b];z//=b
	c+=a[::-1]==a
print c
```

My first Python post, actually my first Python code at all
probably has some golfing potential.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcyxCsMgEADQ2fuKWwpKWoIZDfcl4nBK2gjlImII9edt1je88mv7IcsYiewqlKXpLOVs2hh4HxUjZsHK8tn08hTjQDH5sHYSUNeevxt2xxP5/oi3zjNFUGki9s69bCBiKPVOMcEY9g8)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>105</s> 95 bytes

```js
f=(n,b)=>b?b<2?1:f(n,b-1)+([...s=n.toString(b)].reverse().join``==s):n<2?[1]:[...f(n-1),f(n,n)]
```

### Explanation

Takes a number from 1 to 36 (the limitation of base conversion in JavaScript) and returns an array of the sequence.

Recursive function that checks for palindromes when a base is passed, else returns the sequence if just `n` is passed.

```js
f=(n,b)=>

  // Base palindrome checking
  b?
    b<3?1:                 // return 1 for base-1, since toString(2)
    f(n,b-1)+(             // return the sum of all lower bases and check  this
      [...s=n.toString(b)] // s = n in base b
      .reverse().join``==s // add 1 if it is a palindrome
    )

  // Sequence generation
  :
    n<2?[1]:               // return 1 for the first value of the sequence
    [...f(n-1),f(n,n)]     // return the value for n after the previous values
```

### Test

```js
var solution = f=(n,b)=>b?b<2?1:f(n,b-1)+([...s=n.toString(b)].reverse().join``==s):n<2?[1]:[...f(n-1),f(n,n)]
```

```html
<input type="number" oninput="result.textContent=solution(+this.value)" />
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Is there a way to turn that into a recursive function? I feel like that could save some bytes.

Comment: @ՊՓԼՃՐՊՃՈԲՍԼ You're right. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 88 bytes

```haskell
a!b|a<b=[a]|1>0=mod a b:(div a b)!b
f n=[1+sum[1|x<-[2..y],y!x==reverse(y!x)]|y<-[1..n]]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
bRfU$Lµ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8pKC1UxefQ1kdNa/7//28KAA)

Alternatively:

```
bRŒḂ€Sµ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8p6OikhzuaHjWtCT60FUj@///fFAA)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 73+1 bytes

```php
while(++$i<$argn)$c+=strrev($n=base_convert($argn,10,$i+1))==$n;echo$c+1;
```

works for bases `1` to `36`. Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85ba61651bf57830f7aa8ff228c0b77b5ec28447).

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 92+1 bytes:

```php
for($b=$c=1;$b++<$n=$argn;$c+=$a==array_reverse($a))for($a=[];~~$n;$n/=$b)$a[]=$n%$b;echo$c;
```

works for all bases. Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0897aa4aa94a4bbad8b7402904ccf2f817d3906a).

Answer (score 1):

## ><>, 197+2 Bytes

+2 for -v flag

```
:1+0v    ;n\
1\  \$:@2(?/
:<~$/?)}:{:*}}@:{{
\   \~0${:}
>$:@1(?\::4[:&r&r]:$&@@&%:&@&$@-$,5[1+{]$~{{:@}}$@,$
~~1 \  \
?\~0>$:@2(?\$1-:@3+[}]4[}1-]=
 \  /@@r/!?/
r@+1/)0:<
  /?/$-1$~<
~$/       \-1
```

tio.run doesn't seem to return any output for n>1, but you can verify it on https://fishlanguage.com. Input goes in the "Initial stack" box.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 bytes

```
õ_õ!ìZ èêS
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=9V/1IexaIOjqUw==&input=OA==)

---

### Explanation

```
õ              :Range [1,input]
 _             :Map each Z
  õ            :  Range [1,Z] (let's call each X)
   !ìZ         :   Convert Z to a base X digit array
       è       :  Count
        êS     :   Palindromes
```

Comment: õ_õ hahaha nice emoji

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 85 bytes

```python
def f(a):b,c=2,0;exec'd,m=[],a\nwhile m:d+=[m%b];m/=b\nc+=d[::-1]==d;b+=1;'*a;print c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLDsIgFADAtZ6CjSkIRmEJeSehLPhaEnltSBPx9Dhz/M5tRzVnyoUU6pkOIoISL5NHjksSDawTfsXvVj@ZNJ042HYLzrQnhBUjh2S1fkgHkEzgIM1y9@boFU8SZ9k7GaQi6R7fmUqhJNPXS6GDzT8)

Expects an integer as an argument.

Explanation:

```python
# named function
def f(a):
    # initialize variable to track base (b) and to track palindromes (c)
    b,c=2,0
        # construct code
        '
        # initialize variable to store remainders (m) and to track divisor (d)
        m,d=[],a
        # while d is not zero,
        # add the current remainder to the array
        # and divide d by the base and assign the result back to d
        while d:m+=[m%b];d/=b
        # False == 0 and True == 1, so add 1 to total if m == reversed(m)
        c+=m[::-1]==m;
        # increment base
        # terminate with ; so that next statement can be executed separately
        b+=1;
        '
    # execute constructed statement (a) times
    exec'....................................................'*a
    # print result
    print c
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
mλṁoS=↔`B¹ḣ)ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fc7oc7G/ODbR@1TUlwOrTz4Y7FmkD8//9/UwA)

not sure if I can avoid using a lambda here.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 80 bytes

```javascript
n=>(h=(a,g=n=>n?[n%a,...g(n/a|0)]:[])=>--a<2||(g(n).reverse()+''==g(n))+h(a))(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYnLDsIgEAC/xnQ3PKw92m79kKaHTQWqNGDA9MS/I14mk5k3n5y39Pp8VYhPUy3VQDPsBCwdNQ2PJVxYaq0dhCuXHtf7siLNSvE0lAIto07mNCkbQNF1RP@EYgdGbFZtTOA93Ubvp6EfhfAetxhyPIw@omtPCtuIWH8)

Add 1 at last manually

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Minteger -pa`, 81 bytes

```perl
map{@n=($t="@F")%$_;push@n,$t%$_ while$t/=$_;$\+="@n"eq"@{[reverse@n]}"}2..$_+1}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYpBCsIwEAC/ImEFpTa2SgWRQE7efIFK6WGxgbqNyaqHkK@75jQMMx7D1Ik8B58smRWwUfas1kvoT/4dR0sb4CKL7@gmBN6aEuBWlYsUvpRN14AfDBEt3bPKO62hr9qcRI77w2/27GaKUl863bRNoSPGBwap/fAH)