# Count the Palindromes

Tags: code-golf, integer, base-conversion, palindrome

Given a number `n`, calculate the amount of bases in the range of `[2, n)` in which `b(n)` is a Palindrome.

### Example

`n = 8` has the base conversions:

```
2 = 1000
3 = 22
4 = 20
5 = 13
6 = 12
7 = 11
```

Of which 2 of them, `3 = 22` and `7 = 11` are palindromes. So return `2`.

### Clarifications

- For the sake of convenience, Your answer only needs to be correct for inputs 3 - 36 inclusive, as few languages can handle base conversion of >36.
- A single digit number is considered a palindrome.
- This is sequence A135551 on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A135551)

### Test Cases

```
3   -> 1
4   -> 1
5   -> 2
6   -> 1
7   -> 2
8   -> 2
9   -> 2
10  -> 3
11  -> 1
12  -> 2
13  -> 2
14  -> 2
15  -> 3
16  -> 3
17  -> 3
18  -> 3
19  -> 1
20  -> 3
21  -> 4
22  -> 2
23  -> 2
24  -> 4
25  -> 2
26  -> 4
27  -> 3
28  -> 4
29  -> 2
30  -> 3
31  -> 3
32  -> 3
33  -> 3
34  -> 3
35  -> 2
36  -> 5
```

### Finally

- [Standard Loopholes Apply.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes wins.
- Have Fun!

Comment: Did you mean to write "[2, n)", if so, what does the difference in braces mean?

Comment: @StanStrum Set notion as described in [ISO_31-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-11), Means 2 (inclusive) through n (exclusive)

Comment: I think this might be a dupe of [All your base palindromic belong to us](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69707/9365)?

Comment: "A single digit number is considered a palindrome." But this won't happen anyway.

Comment: @DomHastings I do not think so, as the sequences [A126071](https://oeis.org/A126071/) and [A135551](https://oeis.org/A135551/) differ.

Comment: @JonathanFrech actually I think Dom is right - once the sequences are aligned (one starts at index 0 the other at index 1), A126071(n) = A135551(n) + 1. This is evident from the facts that (a) n in Unary is 00...0 [palindromic]; (b) for n>1, n in base n is 10 [not palindromic]; and (c) n in base n+1 is 11 (or 1 for n=1) [palindromic]. Also it even states in the formula section of A135551 "a(n) = A126071(n) - 1".

Comment: @JonathanAllan Although the sequences are similar, the challenges themselves do also differ in that one requests the other sequence up to n, where as this only requests n. Answers are completely non-transferable between the two.

Comment: While it is true the other asks for up to n, that does not make them non-transferable. The second line of the Jelly submission there, for example, is just calling "link 1" for each number in turn (the only reason it's so much longer than my submission here is that the language has evolved).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire it's a palindrome in n-1 :P

Comment: FYI: My [latest submission in Pyth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141127/53748) shows the ease of porting.

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question, because in my honest opinion the challenges (and tasks) are different enough, and porting the answers there might not be the best option (in some languages, at least).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder, if wrapping something in a loop from 1 to n is not sufficiently trivial a change to be a dupe, what *is* sufficiently trivial?

Comment: @PeterTaylor [Here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39739672#39739672) are the reasons I think it is not a duplicate. Feel free to disagree, but that won't change my opinion.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder, the number of answers an earlier challenge received is nothing to do with whether it's a dupe or not; "*the challenge there is quite old (and many languages have evolved since then, other languages were designed in the mean time*" is an argument for keeping it open in spite of being a dupe [which was also made in this case](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13361/194) to which [see also this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13420/194). If you think an obvious dupe should be reopened in spite of being an obvious dupe, take it to meta first.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Feel free to hammer it again, I don't really have a strong opinion right now. You are probably right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
bḊŒḂ€S
```

A monadic link taking and returning numbers

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/p4Y6uo5Me7mh61LQm@L9xkbHZ0T2H24EcFff/AA)**

#### How?

```
bḊŒḂ€S - Link: number, n
 Ḋ     - dequeue (with implicit range(n) as input) -> [2,3,4,...,n]
b      - convert to base  -> [nb2, nb3, nb4, ..., nbn] (note: nbn is [1,0])
  ŒḂ€  - isPalindrome? for €ach  -> list of 1s and 0s
     S - sum -> number that are palindomes
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E),  <s>10</s>  8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

-2 bytes thanks to Emigna (use "bifurcation" instruction `Â` to replace duplicate and reverse `DR` & increment the loop to avoid needing to close it.)

```
G¹N>вÂQO
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f/dBOvwubDjcF1vrb/P9vZAYA)**

#### How?

```
G¹N>вÂQO
G        - for N in range(1, input()+1):
 ¹       -   1st input
  N      -   N (the loop variable)
   >     -   increment
    в    -   base conversion
     Â   -   push reverse
      Q  -   equal?
       O -   sum
         - print top of stack
```

Comment: You can replace `DR` with `Â`.

Comment: Also, if we know that `n` can't be a palindrome in base `n` you could do `G¹N>вÂQO`.

Comment: We know it's not a palindrome in base n, but it's always a palindrome in base 1, so unless there is a loop for [2,n) or [2,n]... EDIT oh wait you increment, but then don't close the loop before summing, how's that work??

Comment: `G`loops for `[1,n)`, as we incremented `N` it goes from `[2,n]`

Comment: ...but why is no `}` needed before `O`?

Comment: Because we only have the bools we wish to sum on the stack. No residuals. So we can sum each loop iteration. When we get to `O`, the only things on the stack are our sum so far and the value we wish to add to the sum from this iteration.

Comment: Someone can explains me what `bifurcated` means, and why it means `reverse` in `05AB1E`?

Answer (score 2):

## J, 30 bytes

```
[:+/i.&.(-&2)(-:|.)@(#.inv)"0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03BVk8h2kpbP1NPTU9DV81IU0PXqkZP00FDWS8zr0xTySCWiys1OSNfIU3JQAGqyFhTwdj8/38A)

Straightforward solution featuring a lot of parentheses.

## Explanation

```
[: +/ i.&.(-&2) (-:|.)@(#.inv)"0 ]
                                 ]  Right argument, n
      i.&.(-&2)                     Range [2,n)
           -&2                        Subtract 2
      i.                              Create range from n-2
        &.                            Undo subtraction (add 2)
                              "0    For each value in the range
                       (#.inv)      Convert to that base *
                (-:|.)              Palindrome check
                   |.                 Reversed
                 -:                   Matches self (= is rank 0)
   +/                               Sum (i.e. count palindromes)
```

*`#.inv` is used since `#:` expects you to specify the number of digits in the base (it doesn't treat a single argument the way you might expect).

Comment: nice J.  I like the `i.&.(-&2)` trick.

Comment: @Jonah thanks, it's not mine though -- saw it on the Project Euler forums (guess some people like to obfuscate -- or perhaps even golf -- their answers)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 90 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(h(n,i)==h(n,i)[::-1]for i in range(2,n))
h=lambda v,b:v and[v%b]+h(v/b,b)or[]
```

An unnamed function taking `n` that counts the palindromes, which utilises the helper function `h` which performs the base conversions.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RctBCsIwEIXhtT3FbKQJTpG2C0sgXiRmkdDWBOykpDHg6SNVwdXj5/Gtr@QCdWWWt/Iwix0NkNieC3OM0HMpv6uEaFo9hwgePEE0dJ9Yh8R55eTPZbQig6FR5aPVJ8fy2aLlISpddpmmLf1xj/2Fi@qwRk/p8yHUzbVGmNlevLTDGw)**

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 57 bytes

```
Tr@Boole@Table[PalindromeQ@IntegerDigits[#,i],{i,2,#-1}]&
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 47 bytes

```
->n{(2...n).count{|i|(s=n.to_s(i))==s.reverse}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P03BVkHXLq9aw0hPTy9PUy85vzSvpLoms0aj2DZPryQ/vlgjU1PT1rZYryi1LLWoOLW2louLq6C0pFghLTo9taQYpCYz9v9/YzMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth),  <s>10</s>  9 bytes

Port of [irtosiast's submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/69710/53748) to "All your base palindromic belong to us".

-1 byte thanks to FryAmTheEggman - use the filter alias `#` to replace `f` and do away with the `T` (which seems also to have been available back then too).

```
lt_I#jLQS
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P6ck3lM5yycw@P9/IzMA)**

Comment: I don't know if this existed for the previous question, but you can change `f_IT` to `_I#`.

Comment: [Looks like it may well have done](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/blob/c2ab5c69bfaed7fe792de4abe0fdf5dc8fdeb0ff/pyth.py#L187).

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 9 bytes

```
lf_IjQTtS
```

**[Test it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=lf_IjQTtS&input=8&debug=0)**

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 9 bytes

```
sm_IjQdtS
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm_IjQdtS&input=8&debug=0)**

---

## How?

- `sm_IjQdtS`  - Full program with implicit input (`Q` at the end)
- `tS` - All the integers from 2 to the input (inclusive). I chose inclusive because it is golfier and any number `n` converted to base `n` is `10`.
- `m` - Map over the above with a variable `d`.
- `jQd` - Convert the input to base `d` (the current number in the range) as a list.
- `_I` - The best part of this program: Is invariant under reverse? – This checks if the list is palindromic.
- `s` - Sum, which acts like "count the number of truthy results" in this case.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 10 bytes

```
tFOAbD_q)s
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=tFOAbD_q%29s&input=36&warnings=0&hex=0)

```
t          -   input - 1
 FOAbD_q)  -  for i in ^:
  O        -   ^ + 2
   Ab      -    base(input, ^)
     D_q   -     ^ == reversed(^)
         s - sum(^)
```

Comment: Also 10 bytes: `StFAbD_q)s` (porting my Pyth solution)

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 18 bytes

```
x=x1-2R³x\Br³]ier+
```

This is essentially what I used as a reference implementaiton.

### Explained

```
x=x1-2R³x\Br³]ier+
x=                  # Associate 'x' with the implicit input.
  x1-               # Get x - 1
     2R             # Get all numbers in the range 2 through x - 1
           r        # Replace each element by the function...
       ³x\B         # Convert x to base i.
                r   # Replace each element by another function...
            ³]ie    # Duplicate, Inverse, Equals. Checks if it's a palindrome.
                 +  # The sum of. Which counts how many are palindromes.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/7/CtsJQ1yjo0OaKGKeiQ5tjM1OLtP///29kCgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 187 bytes

```python
def P(n):
 p=0
 for b in range(2,n):
	M=0
	while n>=b**M:M+=1
	N,I,B=n,M-1,[]
	while N:
	 for f in range(b)[::-1]:
		if f*b**I<=N:N-=f*b**I;B+=[f];I-=1;break
	p+=0>(B[::-1]==B)*I
 print p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY@7CoNAEEXr3a8YBMHHLvgoAmvGws5CSS8Wim6UhFFECPl6syrBcjhzz52Zv@swUbRtXa/h4ZCrOMwYcNDTAi2MBEtDz96JxI5YYRD7DOO7B0qx9bxCFT6GnJUiFxmSKGQoqvq/U5rIYdKXqXUrpWRYG8RGDdozlvyOpSolnkOS@VjpOsklhkm79M2Ls9nHIHWyM4qYuV5uDl1GWmHe9ga6GmIR31x1QMuOOpCpZZNI9u@2Hw)

A bit on the lengthy side, as there is no built-in used for changing base.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 67 bytes

```hs
0#b=[]
x#b=mod x b:div x b#b
f n=sum[1|b<-[2..n],n#b==reverse(n#b)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/30A5yTY6lqsCSOXmpyhUKCRZpWSWgWjlJK40hTzb4tLcaMOaJBvdaCM9vbxYnTygStui1LLUouJUDSBHM/Z/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCmoKx2X8A) Use by calling `f`. Works with arbitrary high bases.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>77</s> <s>71</s> <s>70</s> <s>68</s> 67 bytes

```js
n=>(g=b=>b<n&&([...s=n.toString(b)].reverse().join``==s)+g(++b))(2)
```

<sup>(Golfed from 77 down to 68 while waiting for the challenge to be reopened)</sup>

---

### Test it

```js
f=
n=>(g=b=>b<n&&([...s=n.toString(b)].reverse().join``==s)+g(++b))(2)
o.innerText=[...Array(34)].map(_=>(""+x).padStart(2)+": "+f(x++),x=3).join`\n`
```

```html
<pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/) `-x`, <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
ò2@sX êS
```

[Test it]https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=8jJAc1gg6lM=&input=MzYKLXg=)

---

### Explanation

```
             :Implicit input of integer U.
ò2           :Range [2,U]
  @          :Map each X
   sX        :  Convert U to a base-X string
      êS     :  Is it a palindrome?
             :Implicitly reduce by addition and output
```