# Non-palindromic numbers

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion, decision-problem, palindrome

**A [strictly non-palindromic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_non-palindromic_number) N is a number that isn't a palindrome in *any* base (in bases 2 to N-2).**  These numbers are listed on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A016038)

For example, the number `19` in base 2,3,4,5,6,...17 is: `10011`,`201`,`103`,`34`,`31`,...`12`.  None of these representations is palindromic, so the number is strictly non-palindromic.

For this challenge, you need to **return a truthy value if the number is non-palindromic, otherwise a falsy value**.

- You may assume the number passed to you is greater than or equal to 0.
- Your program should work for values up to your languages' integer size.

## Test cases:

Truthy:

```
0
1
2
3
4
6
11
19
47
53
79
103
389
997
1459
```

Falsy:

```
5
7
8
9
10
13
16
43
48
61
62
101
113
211
1361
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so make your answers as short as possible!

Comment: Yes, I missed that. However, answers to [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28404/31625) could basically be reused by adding a `result < n-2` check to them, I think.

Answer (score 6):

## C, 82 bytes

```c
p(n,a,b,c,r){c=0;for(b=1;++b<n-2;c+=r==n)for(a=n,r=0;a>0;a/=b)r=r*b+a%b;return!c;}
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/QDQDhS)

### Explanation

This code reverses `n` in base `b` and stores in `r`:

```c
for(a=n,r=0;a>0;a/=b)r=r*b+a%b;
```

The outer loop counts the number of bases from `2` to `n-1` in which `n` is a palindrome.

If `n` is non-palindromic, the count would be `1` (`n` must be a palindrome in base `n-1`).

Comment: Have an upvote because I couldnt upvote the SILOS answer twice

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Best reason to upvote ever.

Comment: @LeakyNun But a bit of serial voting...

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 71 bytes

```python
n=input();b=1
while b<n-2:
 m=n;r=0;b+=1
 while m/(r!=n):r=r*b+m%b;m/=b
```

Output is via [exit code](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5330/12012), where **0** is truthy and **1** is falsy. Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/ETyqKZ).

Answer (score 5):

## [S.I.L.O.S](http://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 206 bytes

```
GOTO e
lbld
c - 1
GOTO c
lble
readIO 
n = i
i - 3
b = i
b + 1
GOTO f
lbla
a = n
r = 0
lblb
m = a
m % b
r * b
r + m
a / b
if a b
r - n
r |
if r d
lblc
c + 1
i - 1
b - 1
lblf
if i a
c / c
c - 1
c |
printInt c
```

[Try it online!](http://silos.tryitonline.net/#code=R09UTyBlCmxibGQKYyAtIDEKR09UTyBjCmxibGUKcmVhZElPIApuID0gaQppIC0gMwpiID0gaQpiICsgMQpHT1RPIGYKbGJsYQphID0gbgpyID0gMApsYmxiCm0gPSBhCm0gJSBiCnIgKiBiCnIgKyBtCmEgLyBiCmlmIGEgYgpyIC0gbgpyIHwKaWYgciBkCmxibGMKYyArIDEKaSAtIDEKYiAtIDEKbGJsZgppZiBpIGEKYyAvIGMKYyAtIDEKYyB8CnByaW50SW50IGM&input=&args=MTk)

Port of [my answer in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91152/48934).

Comment: Have two upvotes one for each answer, because I can't upvote this twice

Comment: pheraps if you can write the code using one separation statement as "|" you can make advantage in write 1 char instead of 2 char of \13 \10 as \n as separation statement

Comment: @RosLuP Am I using \r\n as \n now?

Comment: i don't know in your sys, but i copy above program in a notepad, than save it: the lenght of that file is 241 not 206. so here it seems to me that \n is 2 chars not 1

Comment: @RosLuP Your notepad automatically converted EOLs to \r\n.

Comment: if not for gain one char for "\n", it is because i say it is good to use | as instruction separator (in the add of "\n") for readability reason... here in this place i can not indent that code nor use "\n" so i have no other thing to show or say.

Comment: @RosLuP The `|` is absolute.

Comment: abs is one function one use few time as the C or "|", but one separator is Always used every where so it is better choice one *good* instrution separator first than all other functions, operators, key words label etc. but this is just how i see the subject "instruction separators"

Comment: @RosLuP I am not understanding you. What is your native language?

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <s>75</s> 68 bytes

```
(a!c)b|a<1=c|x<-c*b+mod a b=div a b!x$b
f n=all((/=n).(n!0))[2..n-2]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
bRµ⁼"US<3
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=YlLCteKBvCJVUzwz&input=&args=MTQ1OQ) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=YlLCteKBvCJVUzwzCsOH4oKs4oKsRw&input=&args=WzAsIDEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDYsIDExLCAxOSwgNDcsIDUzLCA3OSwgMTAzLCAzODksIDk5NywgMTQ1OV0sIFs1LCA3LCA4LCA5LCAxMCwgMTMsIDE2LCA0MywgNDgsIDYxLCA2MiwgMTAxLCAxMTMsIDIxMSwgMTM2MV0).

#### How it works

```
bRµ⁼"US<3  Main link. Argument: n

 R         Range; yield [1, ..., n].
b          Convert n to all bases between 1 and n, yielding a 2D array A>
  µ        Begin a new, monadic chain. Argument: A
     U     Upend; reverse the 1D arrays in A.
   ⁼"      Zipwith equal; yield 1 for each array that matches its inverse.
      S    Sum; add the resulting Booleans.
           If n > 1, the sum will be 2 if n is strictly non-palindromic (it is only
           a palindrome in bases 1 and n - 1), and greater than 2 otherwise.
           For 0 and 1, the sum will be 0 (sum of the empty array) and 1 (only a
           palindrome in base 1); both are less than 2.
       <3  Compare the sum with 3, yielding the desired Boolean.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>12</s> 10 bytes

Saved two bytes with Dennis' trick.

```
>3sm_IjQdS
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3E3sm_IjQdS&input=0&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A10%0A997%0A998&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
         S (Q)   Get all the bases we need by building a list from 1 to Q
   m               For all bases d in the bases list:
      jQd           cast Q to base d as a list
    _I              and check to see if the list is palindromic (invariant on reversal)
                  Compile all the results back into a list
  s                Sum the results (a shorter form of any), gives 3 or more for palindromics 
                    (2 is the usual because of bases 1 and Q-1)
>3                 And verify that the sum is greater than three to get non-palindromics
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>58</s> 43 bytes

```
!Or@@Table[#==#~IntegerReverse~i,{i,2,#-2}]&
```

TIL that `#~IntegerReverse~i` reverses the digits of the input when written in base i.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl6, <s>110</s> <s>72</s> 65

```
my &f={?all(map {{.reverse ne$_}(@(.polymod: $^a xx*))},2..$_-2)}
```

Couldn't use base since that's broken for any base above 36.

#### Previous attempts

```
my &a={$^a??flat($a%$^b,a($a div$b,$b))!!()};my &f=-> $n {?all(map {.reverse ne$_ given @(a($n,$_))},2..$n-2)}
my &f=->\n {?all(map {.reverse ne$_ given @(n.polymod: $_ xx*)},2..n-2)}
```

Comment: I managed to get it down to 59 bytes with my first try. Hint use [`.polymod`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/polymod) with an infinite list of divisors. `1362.polymod: 226 xx *`

Comment: Make that 53, and another hint `{...}` and `-> $_ {...}` are almost exactly the same. Also you don't have to store the lambda anywhere so you can remove the `my &f =`.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 83 bytes

```js
f=(n,i=n-2,g=n=>n<i?[n]:[...g(n/i|0),n%i])=>i<2||`${a=g(n)}`!=a.reverse()&&f(n,i-1)
```

```html
<input type=number oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value);><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 14 bytes

```
¬{⟦₆bk∋;?ḃ₍.↔}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFSuVv2obcOjpuZHHcuVSopKU5VqQKy0xJziVKXaciU9BaWHuzprH26d8P/QmupH85c9ampLyn7U0W1t/3BH86OmXr1HbVNq//@PNtBRMNVRMNRRMNdRMNJRsNBRMNZRsNRRMAEKAuXMgBRQwBCowBDEBskA@SZA1SZAtaZAthlIM1DczAikBaTYAChibGEJ0gYyzBJkNNgEE1OQoLGZYSwA)

Outputs through predicate success or failure, which prints `true.` or `false.` if run as a program.

```
¬{           }    It cannot be shown that
        ?         the input
       ; ḃ₍       in a base
      ∋           which is an element of
  ⟦₆              the range from 1 to the input - 1
    b             without its first element
     k            or its last element
           .      can be unified with both the output variable
            ↔     and its reverse.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `GRr`, 58 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 7.25 bytes

```
⇩Ḣƛ?τḂ⁼;a
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJHUnJBPSIsIiIsIuKHqeG4osabP8+E4biC4oG8O2EiLCIiLCIwXG4xXG4yXG4zXG40XG42XG4xMVxuMTlcbjQ3XG41M1xuNzlcbjEwM1xuMzg5XG45OTdcbjE0NTlcbjVcbjdcbjhcbjlcbjEwXG4xM1xuMTZcbjQzXG40OFxuNjFcbjYyXG4xMDFcbjExM1xuMjExXG4xMzYxIl0=)

Bitstring:

```
1101010001101111001011011000000100110010001101101010011011
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 129 bytes

```
f(n,b,k,j){int a[99];for(b=2;b+2<n;++b){for(j=0,k=n;a[j]=k%b,k/=b;++j);for(;k<j&&a[k]==a[j];++k,--j);if(k>=j)return 0;}return 1;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**C, 77 bytes**

```
h(n,b,k,z){for(z=0,k=n;z+=k%b,k/=b;z*=b);return b+3>n?1:z==n?0:h(n,++b,0,0);}
```

recursive exercise...i change (b+2>=n) with (b+3>n) whithout debugging...

```
main()
{int  v[]={0,1,2,3, 4, 6,11,19,47,53,79,103,389,997,1459},
  n[]={5,7,8,9,10,13,16,43,48,61,62,101,113,211,1361}, m;
    // 0 1 2 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  11  12  13   14
 for(m=0; m<15; ++m)
    printf("%u=%u\n", v[m], h(v[m],2,0,0));
 for(m=0; m<15; ++m)
    printf("%u=%u\n", n[m], h(n[m],2,0,0));
}

/*
 77
 0=1
 1=1
 2=1
 3=1
 4=1
 6=1
 11=1
 19=1
 47=1
 53=1
 79=1
 103=1
 389=1
 997=1
 1459=1
 5=0
 7=0
 8=0
 9=0
 10=0
 13=0
 16=0
 43=0
 48=0
 61=0
 62=0
 101=0
 113=0
 211=0
 1361=0
*/
```

Comment: *Do not vandalize your posts.*

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 68 bytes

```php
for($b=$argn;--$b;)strrev($c=base_convert($argn,10,$b))!=$c?:die(1);
```

takes input from STDIN, exits with `1` for falsy, `0` for truthy. Run with `-R`.

Comment: If I see this right you can only solve n<39

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), chars 47, bytes 94

```
{⍵≤4:1⋄∼∨/{⍵≡⌽⍵}¨{⍵{(⍺⍴⍨⌊1+⍺⍟⍵)⊤⍵}w}¨2..¯2+w←⍵}
```

where `{(⍺⍴⍨⌊1+⍺⍟⍵)⊤⍵}` would be the function conversion one positive omega
in digits number base alpha, and `{⍵≡⌽⍵}` would be the function check palindrome...
test:

```
  f←{⍵≤4:1⋄∼∨/{⍵≡⌽⍵}¨{⍵{(⍺⍴⍨⌊1+⍺⍟⍵)⊤⍵}w}¨2..¯2+w←⍵}
  f¨0 1 2 3 4 6 11 19 47 53 79 103 389 997 1459
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
  f¨5 7 8 9 10 13 16 43 48 61 62 101 113 211 1361
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```