# Draw a simple cube

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, geometry, 3d

We don't have a single challenge about drawing a real 3 dimensional cube, so here it goes:

## Challenge

Your task is to draw a rotated, cube with perspective. It can be in a separate window or as an image.

## Input

Your input is 3 separate numbers between 0 and 359.99... These represent the rotation around the x, y and z axis in degrees.

```
0 0 0
30 0 40
95 320 12
```

## Output

You can either display it in a separate window or save an image. You can use any type of display (vector based, rasterized, etc.).

Edit: ASCII is allowed too, to allow golfing languages with only textual output.

The output for rasterized or ASCII graphics must be at least 50*50 (pixels for rasterization, characters for ASCII)

## Additional information

The positive z axis points out from the window, the x axis is horizontal, and the y axis is vertical. Basically the OpenGL standard.

Rotations are counter-clockwise if you look at the cube in the negative direction of a specific axis, e.g looking down for the y axis.

The camera should be on the z axis at a reasonable distance from the cube in the negative z direction, the cube should be at (0;0;0). The. cube also needs to be fully visible, and take up at least 50% of the drawing frame. The camera should look in the positive z direction at the cube.

The rotations of the cube get applied in the x->y->z order.

The cube is rotated around it's center, it doesn't move.

To project a cube in 2d space, you need to divide the x and y coordinates of the cube with the distance parallel to the z-axis between the point and the camera.

## Rules

Rendering libraries are allowed, but the vertices need to be defined in the code. No 3d cube model class.

## Test cases

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be wireframe?

Comment: Care to include an algorithm for the points?

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ No, I made that rule before I thought about rotating it, to prevent people from drawing a simple square, it can be solid.

Comment: @KennyLau I'm not sure what you mean with that.

Comment: @KennyLau google will tell you the formula.

Comment: @Bálint I mean the algorithm for the `projections` of the points into the 2D plane.

Comment: @KennyLau It's usually done by dividing the x and y coordinates with the z.

Comment: What order/directions are the rotations done in? Where is the camera looking from? What kind of projection do we have to use?

Comment: @flawr camera is at 0;0;0, rotations are counter clockwise.

Comment: Counterclockwise from *what* direction? And if the camera is at `0,0,0` then the rotations are going to move the cube out of the field..

Comment: @flawr I included it in the post

Comment: But as I said, the rotations will not work out. As you defined it now, the cube will be moved out of the field of view if e.g. rotated around the x axis. Please use the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1).

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ  `google will tell you the formula.` *No*, challenges should contain as much of the material and information needed to solve them as possible, *included in the body of the post*. I shouldn't have to go googling or Wikipedia-ing just to start understanding.

Comment: @cat true.  That was a mistake.

Comment: related http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22756/15599 . I don't think this is a duplicate, but in the light of this Ï disagree with the first line of this question

Comment: @flawr 's points are valid. If the cube is on z axis, but is then rotated about the x or y axis, it will move off the z axis and out of view. I think you want the cube centred on the origin, so that it rotates about its centre. The camera would then be placed some distance away on the z axis. You should also specify how far, otherwise I would make the distance infinity to avoid having to deal with perspective, and simply do an orthogonal projection: x2d=x3d, y2d=y3d, z3d ignored. For a cube of  sidelength 2 and hence vertices (+/-1,+/-1,+/-1) a camera at (0, 0,10 to 20) would be appropriate.

Comment: Once that is sorted, the only other point is to mention the order in which the rotations are done, and I'd be ready to cast a reopen vote.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ I hope it's clear now.

Comment: There is still a contradiction here: `cube rotates about its center` + `cube rotates about x,y,z axes` means cube must be at 0,0,0 (which is where you say the camera is.) As I said before, the easiest way to resolve this is to rotate about the origin and move the camera to some point on the z axis. Alternatively it would have to be '[3 numbers] represent the rotation about the z axis and axes parallel to x and y axes that pass through its centre'. You would also be wise to specify exactly how many cube sidelengths away the camera should be.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt Done

Comment: Reminds me of this thing I did... https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114767 Relevant for if you need to find some code for calculating perspective 3D points and what-not.

Comment: Would answers in Unity count?

Comment: @Blue If you write a code, wich generates the vertices for it.

Comment: @Bálint lol I'd post my OpenGL answer but then you know... its OpenGL and it takes 2 pages....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com/) (Ruby) <s>235</s> 231

Everything computed from scratch.

```
Shoes.app{p,a,b,c=ARGV.map{|j|j.to_f/90}
k=1+i="i".to_c
p=(0..3).map{|j|y,z=(k*i**(j+a)).rect
x,z=(((-1)**j+z*i)*i**b).rect
q=(x+y*i)*i**c
[90*(k+q/(z-4)),90*(k+q/(4+z))]}
4.upto(15){|j|line *(p[j%4][0].rect+p[(j+j/4)%4][1].rect)}}
```

Call from commandline eg `shoes cube3d.rb 0 30 0`

The idea is to simultaneously generate / rotate the four vertices of a tetrahedron in 3d. Then, as these are reduced to 2d, we generate the four vertices of the inverse tetrahedron (the total 8 vertices being those of the cube.) This gives 4 pairs of vertices corresponding to the 4 body diagonals. Finally the 2d vertices are connected by lines: each vertex of the original tetrahedron must be connected to each vertex of the inverse tetrahedron forming the 12 edges and 4 body diagonals of the cube. The ordering ensures the body diagonals are not plotted.

**Test cases output**

Note that, to be consistent with the last two test cases, rotation about the z axis is clockwise from the POV of the viewer. This seems to be in contradiction with the spec however. Rotation direction can be reversed by modifying `*i**c` -> `/i**c`

[image]

**ungolfed**

```
Shoes.app{
  p,a,b,c=ARGV.map{|j|j.to_f/90}   #Throw away first argument (script name) and translate next three to fractions of a right angle.
  k=1+i="i".to_c                   #set up constants i=sqrt(-1) and k=1+i

  p=(0..3).map{|j|                 #build an array p of 4 elements (each element wil be a 2-element array containing the ends of a body diagonal in complex number format)
    y,z=(k*i**(j+a)).rect          #generate 4 sides of square: 1+i,i-1,-1-i,-i+1, rotate about x axis by a, and store in y and z as reals 
    x,z=(((-1)**j+z*i)*i**b).rect  #generate x axis displacements 1,-1,1,-1, rotate x and z about y axis by b, store in x and z as reals
    q=(x+y*i)*i**c                 #rotate x and y about z axis, store result in q as complex number
  [90*(k+q/(z-4)),90*(k+q/(4+z))]} #generate "far" vertex q/(4+z) and "near" vertex q/-(4-z) opposite ends of body diagonal in 2d format.

  4.upto(15){|j|                   #iterate through 12 edges, use rect and + to convert the two complex numbers into a 4 element array for line method
    line *(p[j%4][0].rect+         #cycle through 4 vertices of the "normal" tetrahedron
     p[(j+j/4)%4][1].rect)         #draw to three vertices of the "inverted" tetrahedron. j/4=1,2,3, never 0
  }                                #so the three edges are drawn but the body diagonal is not.
}
```

Note that for historical reasons a scale factor of 90 is applied in line 9 (chosen to be the same as 90 degrees in line 2 for golfing) but in the end there was no golfing advantage in using this particular value, so it has become an arbitrary choice.

Answer (score 4):

### HTML/CSS/JS, 739 bytes, probably non-competing

But I just wanted to show off CSS 3D transforms.

```js
w=_=>o.style.transform=`rotateZ(${z.value}deg) rotateY(${y.value}deg) rotateX(${-x.value}deg)`
```

```css
input {
  width: 5em;
}

#c{width:90px;height:90px;margin:90px;position:relative;perspective:180px}#o{position:absolute;width:90px;height:90px;transform-style:preserve-3d;transform-origin:45px 45px 0px;}#o *{position:absolute;width:90px;height:90px;border:2px solid black}#f{transform:translateZ(45px)}#b{transform:rotateX(180deg)translateZ(45px)}#r{transform:rotateY(90deg)translateZ(45px)}#l{transform:rotateY(-90deg)translateZ(45px)}#u{transform:rotateX(90deg)translateZ(45px)}#d{transform:rotateX(-90deg)translateZ(45px)}
```

```html
<div oninput=w()>
  X:<input id="x" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="360">
  Y:<input id="y" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="360">
  Z:<input id="z" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="360">
</div>
<!-- Above code for ease of use of snippet. Golfed version: <div oninput=w()><input id=x><input id=y><input id=z></div> -->

<div id=c><div id=o><div id=f></div><div id=b></div><div id=r></div><div id=l></div><div id=u></div><div id=d>
```

Comment: This actually looks pretty neat. I experienced with CSS3 transformations before, but I had issues with it.

Comment: You seem to have the rotations in the wrong order. It should be x then y then z. You have z then y then x. @Bálint may confirm.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt When I wrote this I didn't know what the order should be, and I couldn't work it out from the test cases, so thanks for updating me. I've also flipped the direction of the X rotation, so now I match all of the test cases.

Comment: Can you still provide a byte count? Even if answers are non-competing they should always have a byte count

Comment: @Downgoat Golfed or ungolfed?

Comment: @Neil golfed, all answers to [tag:code-golf] should be golfed to be valid submissions

Answer (score 0):

## Maple, <s>130+14</s> (in progress)

```
with(plots):f:=(X,Y,Z)->plot3d(0,x=0..1,y=0..1,style=contour,tickmarks=[0,0,0],labels=["","",""],axes=boxed,orientation=[Z,-X,Y]);
```

[image]

This plots a constant function inside a box, then uses plot options to hide ticks, labels and the function itself. Adding `projection=.5` to the options brings the camera closer, enabling perspective view.
I wrote this before the specs were finalized and the rotation order is `x, y', z''` instead of `x, y, z`. Until I fix the angles, here is another solution

## POV-Ray, 182

```
#include"a.txt"
#include"shapes.inc"
camera{location 9*z look_at 0}
light_source{9*z color 1}
object{Wire_Box(<-2,-2,-2>,<2,2,2>,.01,0)texture{pigment{color rgb 1}}rotate<R.x,-R.y,-R.z>}
```

reads input through the `a.txt` file which should contain
`#declare R=<xx,yy,zz>;`
with `xx,yy,zz` being the rotation angles

[image]

Comment: Yay for using POV-ray, it's a great program. Unfortunately, the rules now state that no 3d cube class can be used.