# Find the smallest prime from a substring

Tags: code-golf, primes

In 1946 Erdos and Copeland proved that [a certain number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copeland%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_constant) is a [normal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number), i.e. the digits in its decimal expansion are uniformly distributed.

Users will input a sequence of digits and you will find the smallest prime that contains that string in base 10.

Example:

```
input   -> output
"10"    -> 101
"03"    -> 103
"222"   -> 2221
"98765" -> 987659
```

**Shortest code in bytes** wins. I do know that some languages (mathematica, sage, pari-gp...) come with built-in functions related to primes. **-50 bytes** if your program doesn't rely on such functions. Don't try to cheat on this please, if your language already has a huge advantage don't claim the bonus.

### Edit

According to a few comments below, the smallest prime that contains "03" is 3. Does this really make a difference? The only thing I can think of is that maybe numbers are easier to handle than strings.

In cases like "03" the preferred output would be 103. However, I don't consider it to be the fundamental part of your program, so you're free to ignore any leading zero if it grants you a lower byte count.

Comment: This seems like a nice base for a Project Euler task

Comment: The smallest prime containing "03" is 03. Maybe you should add a rule clarifying that the input may contain leading zeros but the output may not.

Comment: @steveverrill there's no such number as 03. If you meant 3, then that doesn't  contain "03".

Comment: @JanDvorak 03 is a valid representation of the number 3. (2.9... recurring infinitely, equivalent to 2+9/9, is also considered by some a valid representation.) I understand from the example given that 03 is not an acceptable representation for this question. This is a pedant point, but given the usual abuse of the rules, one I think is worth making.

Comment: I think the better way to phrase it would be to find the smallest number that, when converted to a string, would contain "03".

Comment: This seems like it'd be a fun fastest code challange

Answer (score 13):

## Golfscipt, <del>33</del> 32 bytes = -18 score

```
2{:x,2>{x\%!},!!x`3$?)!|}{)}/;;x
```

Explanation:

- `2{...}{)}/` - starting with `2`, while something is true, increment the top of the stack
- `;;x` - discard the intermediate values collected by `{}{}/` and the input, then put the last value tested there
- `:x,2>` - store the value as `x`, then produce a list from `2` to `x-1`
- `{x\%!},!!` - keep those that `x` is divisible by, then coerce to boolean (not empty)
- `` x`3?)! `` - look up the input in the text form of `x` (`-1` if not found), increment, negate.
- `|` - or

Answer (score 7):

#### Haskell program, 97 characters = 47 score

```
main=getLine>>= \i->print$head$[x|x<-[2..],all((/=0).mod x)[2..x-1],i`Data.List.isInfixOf`show x]
```

#### Haskell function, 75 characters = 25 score

```
p i=head$[x|x<-[2..],all((/=0).mod x)[2..x-1],i`Data.List.isInfixOf`show x]
```

the type of `p` is `(Integral a, Show a) => [Char] -> a`. If you supply your own integral type, you can lookup by infix in your own representation of those values. The standard `Integer` uses the expected decimal notation for integers.

Not very fast. Quadratic in the value (not size) of the output.

ungolfed version:

```
import Data.List
leastPrime infix = head $ filter prime' [2..]
  where prime' x  = all (\n-> x`mod`n /= 0) [2..x-1]
                 && i `isInfixOf` show x
main = print . leastPrime =<< getLine
```

example:

```
Prelude> let p i=head$[x|x<-[2..],all((/=0).mod x)[2..x-1],i`Data.List.isInfixOf`show x]
Prelude> p "0"
101
Prelude> p "00"
1009
Prelude> p "000" -- long pause
10007
```

Answer (score 3):

**Java - 175 characters.**

```
class s{public static void main(String[]a){int i,n=2,p;for(;;){p=1;for(i=3;i<n;i++)if(n%i==0)p=0;if((n==2||p>0)&&(""+n).indexOf(a[0])>=0) {System.out.println(n);break;}n++;}}}
```

Comment: You can save 1 character by dropping the space between `indexOf(a[0])>=0)` and `{System.out.println(n)`.

Comment: I think you can easily save (about 8) characters by replacing your `boolean p=true` by something like `int p=1` and so on.

Comment: declaring all your ints at once will further reduce your program size.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica 58

```
(n=1;While[StringCases[ToString[p=Prime@n],#]=={},n++];p)&
```

---

**Relative Timings** on my Mac (2.6 GHz i7 with 8 GB memory).

Find the smallest prime containing "01".

```
AbsoluteTiming[(n = 1; While[StringCases[ToString[p = Prime@n], #] == {}, n++]; p) &["01"]]
```

> {0.000217, 101}

---

Find the smallest prime containing "012345".

```
AbsoluteTiming[(n = 1; While[StringCases[ToString[p = Prime@n], #] == {}, n++]; p) &["012345"]]
```

> {5.021915, 10123457}

---

Find the smallest prime containing "0123456".

```
AbsoluteTiming[(n = 1; While[StringCases[ToString[p = Prime@n], #] == {}, n++]; p) &["0123456"]]
```

> {87.056245, 201234563}

Comment: You can use `StringFreeQ` to make it shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [Sage](http://sagemath.org), 72

Runs in the interactive prompt

```
a=raw_input()
i=0
p=2
while a not in str(p):i+=1;p=Primes().unrank(i)
p
```

`Primes().unrank(i)` gives the `i`th prime number, with the 0th prime being 2.

Answer (score 2):

#### R, 56chars -50 = 6

```
k=2;n=scan(,"");while(!grepl(n,k)|sum(!k%%2:k)>1)k=k+1;k
```

Take input as stdin. Increments k until k is a prime (tested by summing the instances for which k mod 2 to k are zeroes, hence FALSE since 0 turned into a logical is FALSE) and contains the string given as input (tested with a simple grep, here grepl since we want a logical as result).

Usage:

```
> k=2;n=scan(,"");while(!grepl(n,k)|sum(!k%%2:k)>1)k=k+1;k
1: "03"
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 103
> k=2;n=scan(,"");while(!grepl(n,k)|sum(!k%%2:k)>1)k=k+1;k
1: "003"
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 2003
```

Answer (score 2):

## shell oneliner (coreutils): 45chars

Not defining a function here... just a oneliner that takes one argument in `$n` and scans the integer range (actually a bit more to make code shorter). The 55 character version:

```
seq 5e9|grep $n|factor|awk '{if(NF==2)print $2}'|head -n1
```

It's not even too slow. For `n=0123456` it returns `201234563` in `81.715s`. That's impressively fast for a long pipeline with two string processors.

Removing two characters (down to 53) and one pipe, we can get it running even faster:

```
seq 5e9|grep $n|factor|awk '{if(NF==2){print $2;exit}}'
```

And finally, some `sed` wizardry to bring it down to **45 characters**, although the printout is ugly:

```
seq 5e9|grep $n|factor|sed -n '/: \w*$/{p;q}'
```

> n=000 -> 10007: 10007 (user 0.017s)
>
> n=012345 -> 10123457: 10123457 (user 7.11s)
>
> n=0123456 -> 201234563: 201234563 (user 66.8s)

Answer (score 2):

## J - 38 char -50 = -12 pts

Normally in J, you'd be using the very optimized builtins dedicated to primes, so I'm not going to apologize for any slowness in execution.

```
>:@]^:(>./@(E.":)*:]=*/@(+.i.)@])^:_&2
```

Explained:

- `>:@]^:(...)^:_&2` - Starting with 2, increment until `(...)` returns false.
- `(+.i.)@]` - Take the GCD of the counter with every integer smaller than it. (We use the convention GCD(X,0) = X.)
- `]=*/@` - Take the product of all these numbers, and test for equality to the counter. If the counter is prime, the list was all 1s, except for the GCD with 0; else there will be at least one GCD that is greater than 1, so the product will be greater than the counter.
- `>./@(E.":)` - Test if the string representation of the counter (`":`) contains the string (`E.`) at any point. `>./` is the max function, and we use it because `E.` returns a boolean vector with a 1 wherever the substring begins in the main string.
- `*:` - Logical NAND the results together. This will be false only if both inputs were true, i.e. if the counter both was prime and contained the substring.

Usage:

```
   >:@]^:(>./@(E.":)*:]=*/@(+.i.)@])^:_&2 '03'
103
   >:@]^:(>./@(E.":)*:]=*/@(+.i.)@])^:_&2 '713'
2713
```

For posterity, here's the version using the prime builtin (30 char long, but no bonus):

```
>:@]^:(>./@(E.":)*:1 p:])^:_&2
```

`1 p:]` tests the counter for primality, instead of the GCD trick.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (v2), 3 bytes in Brachylog's encoding

```
ṗ≜s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf96htw6OmxvL/D3dOf9Q5p/j/fzMjAA)

Function submission, taking input from the right-hand argument, giving output by mutating the left-hand argument. (This is the opposite of the normal Brachylog convention; see [this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10276/acceptable-ways-of-using-input-and-output-variables-in-brachylog) for more discussion. Swapping the arguments into the more usual order would cost three bytes.) The TIO link has a wrapper which calls the function with the appropriate calling convention and prints the result.

### Explanation

```
ṗ≜s
 ≜   Find the integer closest to zero
ṗ      which is prime {implicit: and output it via the left argument}
  s    and which is a substring of the {right argument}
```

Sadly, Brachylog is so appropriate for this problem that according to the rules in the problem, I can't even attempt to go for the bonus (which ironically means that it's incapable of winning).

One of the reasons I like Brachylog so much is that programming is a communication between human and computer, and thus a "perfect" language would let you just translate the problem specification into English directly; the ideas via which the problem was stated, and via which the program is written, would be the same. Brachylog can hit this ideal surprisingly often; the question here is "find the smallest prime containing a given substring", and I can literally string together the concepts of "smallest, prime, containing substring" in the correct order and have a working program. As such, Brachylog says much more about the nature of communication than a language in which you had to explicitly specify an algorithm for solving the problem would; sometimes when talking to other humans, we try to explain a problem by explaining the steps you'd take to solve it, but that's rare. So why should our languages be any different?

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript 83 bytes = 33 score

Golfed:

```
for(s=prompt(n=x=0);!n;x++)for(n=(''+x).match(s)?2:0;n&&n<x;n=x%n?n+1:0);alert(x-1)
```

Ungolfed (a bit):

```
s=prompt() // get the input
n = 0
for(x=0;!n;x++) // stop when n is non-zero
    if ((''+x).match(s)) { // if x matches the pattern, check if x is prime
        for(n=2;n&&n<x;)
            n = (x%n == 0) ? 0 : n+1; // if x%n is zero, x is not prime so set n=0
        // if n is non-zero here, x is prime and matches the pattern
    }
alert(x-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (Node.JS) - 93 bytes = 43 points

```
l:for(i=x=process.argv[2];j=i;i++){while(--j>2)if(!(i%j*(""+i).match(x)))continue l
throw i}
```

In extracted form with sensible variable names:

```
outerLoop:for (currentTry=inputNumber=process.argv[2]; primeIterator=currentTry; currentTry++ ) {
    while (--primeIterator > 2) 
        if(!(currentTry % primeIterator * (""+currentTry).match(inputNumber)))
            continue outerLoop;
    throw i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Rust 0.9 136 bytes = 86 points

```
fn main(){
   let mut n:u32=2;
   while n.to_str().find_str(std::os::args()[1])==None ||
         range(2,n).find(|&x|n%x==0)!=None {
      n=n+1;
   }
   print!("{}",n);
}
```

Very explicit despite for compactness.
Too much space spent on the string find. :(

Here the version without whitespace (136 char)

```
fn main(){let mut n:u32=2;while n.to_str().find_str(std::os::args()[1])==None||range(2,n).find(|&x|n%x==0)!=None{n=n+1;}print!("{}",n);}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, 10 bytes

```
_j *ZsøU}a
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=X2ogKlpz+FV9YQ==&input=Ijgi)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>80</s> 79 bytes - 50 = <s>30</s> 29 score

-1 byte thanks to @ASCII-only's creative use of `%s` instead of `str`

<s>Test case "98765" has not been confirmed yet because of how long it is taking to test</s> Confirmed for test case "98765" after a couple of hours, but with a similar approach that utilizes short-circuit evaluation to avoid some primality testing it works much faster. Alternatively, this can be ~2x as fast if we know that "2" is not an input (we can avoid checking even numbers for primality) by setting `i=3` initially and `i+=2` in the loop, at no extra byte cost.

```python
def f(x):
 i=2
 while(x in"%s"%i)*all(i%j for j in range(2,i))-1:i+=1
 return i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7LCsIwEEXX5isuKYXEBzQpPlroB7hy405cFE3tSE0lTVHBf6@poKuZcwbm3vvL161Nh@FsKlTiKXMGKjTDo6bGiCfI8rjjMclp2TSC4iuq1uEaPFxpL0boOUm5UDnNCsXgjO@dBQ3edP5UdqZDgQObcJXwORBBJSpQkv4oDaS1DhghzHCMwLPNerX8qu@W4Q1Pt/Cr7T1ai/12x46MjU3GnLHMPy9nk7sj60UlRifl8AE)

Explanation of the `while` condition (`(x in"%s"%i)*all(i%j for j in range(2,i))-1`):

`(x in"%s"%i)`: `True`/`1` if the current counter contains the desired sequence of numbers in it; `False`/`0` otherwise.

`all(i%j for j in range(2,i))`: `True`/`1` if the current counter always has a remainder when divided by any integer from 2 (inclusive) to itself (exclusive), i.e. is prime; `False`/`0` otherwise.

The `*` multiplies the two conditions together, and acts as an `and` operator - the product is `True`/`1` if and only if both conditions are `True`/`1`.

The `-1` acts as a `not` operator: `False`/`0` - 1 results in `-1`, which is considered true, whereas `True`/`1` - 1 results in `0`, which is considered false. Thus, the loop continues while the number either does not contain the desired sequence of numbers or is not prime.

Replace the `*` with `and` and add parentheses around everything but the `-1` for a much faster, equivalent solution (that is slightly longer).

A **76 byte - 50 = 26 score** solution in Python 2 given by @ASCII-only (utilizes ``` `` ``` instead of `str()`,

```python
def f(x):
 i=2
 while(x in`i`)*all(i%j for j in range(2,i))-1:i+=1
 return i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BSsNAEIbP3af4SRB3NYVki60N5AE8efEmQtN2Yqaku2Ez1QZ897gp6Gnm@waGrx@l9c4u@7Efp@lIDRp9NaUCV1bhu@WO9BXsdrwzD3XXab47ofEBpygRavdJ2mZszLIo@bEqFALJJTjwJDTIoR5oQIV3tUiKPMmAFEVeRMpXf7SKZK2NmCLOeEyRbJ8366ebum1b/ED4HH/5i8A7vL28ZmjrL3L3gj2RQ73vCOJx8K7hcAYLRhL1odScO8fMxf9RpVr0gZ3oRs/OmOkX)

Comment: [why not py2](https://tio.run/##PY7BSsNAEIbP3af4SRB3NYVki60N5AE8efEmQtN2Yqaku2Ez1QZ897gp6Gnm@waGrx@l9c4u@7Efp@lIDRp9NaUCV1bhu@WO9BXsdrwzD3XXab47ofEBpygRavdJ2mZszLIo@bEqFALJJTjwJDTIoR5oQIV3tUiKPMmAFEVeRMpXf7SKZK2NmCLOeEyRbJ8366ebum1b/ED4HH/5i8A7vL28ZmjrL3L3gj2RQ73vCOJx8K7hcAYLRhL1odScO8fMxf9RpVr0gZ3oRs/OmOkX)

Comment: @ASCII-only I haven't used python 2 much and mostly use python 3, so that's what I golf in. Though it seems that most of the time python 2 ends up being shorter...

Comment: You did a typo, in the first one you have `return I`

Comment: [79](https://tio.run/##PY7LasMwEEXX0VdcZEyl1gU/6CMGf0BX3XRXulCScT3BkYI8aRPov7tyoF3NnDMwnONFhuCbed5Rj96cbavAXa3wPfBI5gz2Op90zvbWjaPhfI8@ROyTR3T@k0xdsLX3Vct3XaUQSU7Rg2ehSbZuogkd3tVKV6UugAxVWSUqmz9qEtV1nTBDmumYQa@fnx4fruq6rfED4UP6FU6C4PH28lpgcF/kbwQbIg@3GQkSsA2@53gACy4k6kOpJXeJWYr/o1q1Okb2YnqzOGvnXw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tidy](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Tidy), 37 bytes

```
{s:s&{s,p:s in"".p}from primes|first}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcXNCgIhFAbQfU/xcRelYDIZ/QnTu4iNIDSTeIUI89mt2ZxT4uPTgx17ZcvbyipZRlyIdGohv2akHOeJvyFmLq0XDzvCCzoMpEDDcdUYs3a7Xs4nkpvZJVHhYPHOsUzPRexIO/2HsL@DdBBOSjSF4mX/AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 36 - 50 = -14 points

```perl6
{$^a;first {/$a/&&$_%%one ^$_},2..*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYtLC4JAFEb38ysuwyiaOr7IEklq0a5ltPGFixEEU/HaIsTfPk1FdFfncL8ziqmL5P0JegMHkAsr66RpJ5xhcVnt6jqrNG3oBZSsWu2A880qHyjgKnBOCFHhcVaIKja6thdopinHsWtnw83Ryp08zdE11XTs6h6s71ppM0y/dCEALUJj8Mwr@Pl2upg2z/yCrJL6HgV1Tgq@5xPqhX8NCQ2CgH5VkXrH@120pW//UPwC)

Considering `$_%%one ^$_` is the only 2 bytes <s>smaller</s> larger than `.is-prime`, I think it's worth it for the bonus. This times out for the last test case.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                                  }  # Anonymous code block
 $^a;                                 # Assign input to $a
     first                    ,2..*   # Find the first number
           {                 }        # Which
            /$a/                        # Contains the input
                &&                      # And
                  $_%%one ^$_           # Is prime
```

Comment: 2 bytes smaller?

Comment: lol @ the part in the question that says "Don't try to cheat on this please, if your language already has a huge advantage don't claim the bonus."

Comment: @ASCII-only Well, I'm still being beaten by GolfScript, so... `:$`

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 65 - 50 = 15 points

```javascript
x=>(f=y=>(''+y).match(x)&&(p=n=>--n<2||y%n&&p(n))(y)?y:f(y+1))(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcvRCoIwFMbx@96jeQ4yyXlVNnsUGWuWpdtwEjvgu6/dht188P/B91IfFfQy@pUHP97NMjv7NpR6maLsYJCUtyhKwmpWq35CRMbASys7zu1VbBsdLWMeLCIQ3ugyAJV1johJOxvcZKrJPaCHBrE9/FJ92psQYo/Nn/M5U/oC)